# Can't get monit to run "exec" actions

Tags: centos, monit

I've got a working `monit` installation on CentOS 6.5.  Events are getting detected and alert mail is getting sent, but I'm trying to get other things to happen when an event fires, via the `exec` feature, and none of these are working.

For instance, I have a rule like:

```
if cpu usage (user) > 10% then 
   exec "/bin/echo 'user limit' >> /tmp/monit-status-log" as uid someuser and gid somegroup
```

The rule fires appropriately under cpu load, but nothing is written into the file (whose protection setting is rw-rw-rw).

The log file for an execution looks correct as far as it goes, I guess:

```
[PST Feb 20 09:31:04] info     : 'linux2.example.com' Monit reloaded
[PST Feb 20 09:31:31] info     : Reinitializing monit daemon
[PST Feb 20 09:31:31] info     : Awakened by the SIGHUP signal
[PST Feb 20 09:31:31] info     : Reinitializing monit - Control file '/etc/monit.conf'
[PST Feb 20 09:31:31] info     : Shutting down monit HTTP server
[PST Feb 20 09:31:32] info     : monit HTTP server stopped
[PST Feb 20 09:31:32] info     : Starting monit HTTP server at [*:2812]
[PST Feb 20 09:31:32] info     : monit HTTP server started
[PST Feb 20 09:31:32] info     : 'linux2.example.com' Monit reloaded
[PST Feb 20 09:32:32] error    : 'linux2.example.com' cpu user usage of 24.4% matches resource limit [cpu user usage>10.0%]
[PST Feb 20 09:32:32] info     : 'linux2.example.com' exec: /bin/echo
[PST Feb 20 09:33:32] info     : 'linux2.example.com' 'linux2.example.com' cpu user usage check succeeded [current cpu user usage=0.0%]
```

Any thoughts or advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should setup the `exec` command like this to make it works as expected :

```
if cpu usage (user) > 10% then
  exec "/bin/bash -c '/bin/echo user limit >> /tmp/monit-status-log'" as uid someuser and gid somegroup
```